# How to redirect users depending on the return value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am struggling with JavaScript right now. 
someone wrote this code and I am trying to understand it. 
what's the best way to redirect users depending on their location ?

currently, we figure out their area by using their areadcode in their phone# as you see in the javaScript.

This is the form.

```
<div class="row"> 
  <!-- Homework for Jason Begin -->
  <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3"> 
    <!-- Homework for Jason End -->
    <form id="sfDemoForm" action="https://webto.salesforce.com/servlet/servlet.WebToLead?encoding=UTF-8" method="POST" class="sky-form">
      <input name="captcha_settings" value="{&quot;keyname&quot;:&quot;IC_ClearDent_Main_Demo&quot;,&quot;fallback&quot;:&quot;true&quot;,&quot;orgId&quot;:&quot;00D1I0000002QyG&quot;,&quot;ts&quot;:&quot;&quot;}" type="hidden">
      <input name="oid" value="00D1I0000002QyG" type="hidden">
      <input name="retURL" value="https://test.cleardent.com/demo-thankyou-bc.html" type="hidden">

      <!--  ----------------------------------------------------------------------  --> 
      <!--  NOTE: These fields are optional debugging elements. Please uncomment    --> 
      <!--  these lines if you wish to test in debug mode.                          --> 
      <!--  <input type="hidden" name="debug" value=1>                              --> 
      <!--  <input type="hidden" name="debugEmail" value="ppli@cleardent.com">      --> 
      <!--  ----------------------------------------------------------------------  -->

      <fieldset>
        <!--<label class="label" for="first_name">First Name</label>-->
        <label class="input margin-bottom-15"><i class="icon-prepend fa fa-user"></i>
          <input  id="sffirst_name" maxlength="40" name="first_name" size="20" type="text" required placeholder="First name">
        </label>
        <!--<label class="label" for="last_name">Last Name</label>-->
        <label class="input margin-bottom-15"><i class="icon-prepend fa fa-user"></i>
          <input  id="sflast_name" maxlength="80" name="last_name" size="20" type="text" required placeholder="Last name">
        </label>
        <!--<label class="label" for="email">Email</label>-->
        <label class="input margin-bottom-15"><i class="icon-prepend fa fa-envelope"></i>
          <input id="sfemail" maxlength="80" name="email" size="20" type="email" required placeholder="Email address">
        </label>
        <!-- <label class="label" for="phone">Phone</label>-->
        <label class="input margin-bottom-25"><i class="icon-prepend fa fa-phone"></i>
          <input id="sfphone" maxlength="40" name="phone" size="20" type="text" required placeholder="Phone">
        </label>
        <!--<label class="label" for="description">Notes</label>-->
        <label class="textarea textarea-resizable margin-bottom-25">
          <textarea id="sfdescription" name="description" placeholder="Is there something specific you want to see from ClearDent?"></textarea>
        </label>
        <input id="sfstate" name="state" type="hidden">
        <input id="sflead_source" name="lead_source" type="hidden" value="Website">
        <input id="sfcompany" name="company" type="hidden">
        <input id="sfCampaign_ID" name="Campaign_ID" type="hidden" value="7011I000000d5auQAA">
      </fieldset>
      <div id="recaptcha" class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="6LeXmEAUAAAAAG7VJd6Z8YCVkP44AgAlqCUmpRAi" data-callback="submitDemoToLead" data-size="invisible"> </div>
      <footer>
        <button id="sfdemoPreSubmit" class="btn-u"><i class="fa fa-paper-plane fa-fw"></i> Get Your Free Demo</button>
        <button class="btn-u btn-brd" onclick="window.history.back();"><i class="fa fa-arrow-left fa-fw"></i> Back</button>
      </footer>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is the JavaScript

```
    <script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js"></script> 
<script>  
  //Required Salesforce functions
  function timestamp() {
    var response = document.getElementById("g-recaptcha-response");
    if (response == null || response.value.trim() == "") {
      var elems = JSON.parse(document.getElementsByName("captcha_settings")[0].value);
      elems["ts"] = JSON.stringify(new Date().getTime());
      document.getElementsByName("captcha_settings")[0].value = JSON.stringify(elems);
    }
  }
  window.setInterval(timestamp, 500); 

  //Masking
  $("#sfphone").mask('(999) 999-9999', {placeholder:'X'});

  //Form helper functions
  function getProvince(pStrPhone) {
    var areacode = pStrPhone.substring(0, 3);
    switch (areacode) {
      case "403":
      case "780":
      case "587":
      case "825":
        return "AB";
      case "604":
      case "778":
      case "250":
      case "236":
        return "BC";
      case "204":
      case "431":
        return "MB";
      case "506":
        return "NB";
      case "709":
        return "NL";
      case "867":
        return "YT";
      case "902":
      case "782":
        return "NS";
      case "416":
      case "647":
      case "437":
      case "519":
      case "226":
      case "548":
      case "613":
      case "343":
      case "705":
      case "249":
      case "807":
      case "905":
      case "289":
      case "365":
        return "ON";
      case "418":
      case "581":
      case "450":
      case "579":
      case "514":
      case "438":
      case "819":
      case "873":
        return "QC";
      default:
        return "";
    }
  }  

  function cleanPhNum(pStrPhone) {
    return pStrPhone.replace("-", "").replace("(", "").replace(")","").replace(" ", "");
  }
  //Form validation and reCAPTCHA
    //Jason Home Work - jQuery Validate and figure out how it validates
  $("#sfdemoPreSubmit").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#sfcompany").val($("#sflast_name").val() + ", " + $("#sffirst_name").val());
    $("#sfphone").val(cleanPhNum($("#sfphone").val()));
    $("#sfstate").val(getProvince($("#sfphone").val()));
    $("#sfDemoForm").validate();
    if ($("#sfDemoForm").valid()) {
       grecaptcha.execute();
    }
  });

  function submitDemoToLead(token) {
    $("#sfDemoForm").submit();  

  }
```

This is my poor attempt. right below the JavaScript code above.

```
  function redirect() {
  var province = document.getElementById('#sfstate').value;
    if(province == 'BC')
    {
        location.href = "www.xxx.com/bc";
    }
    if(province == 'AB')
    {
        location.href = "www.xxx.com/ab";
    }
    if(province == 'ON')
    {
        location.href = "www.xxx.com/on";
    }
    else
    {
        alert("Invalid Input");
    }
}
```

I am literally pulling my hair off.

Please help me!!

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in your redirect function.  You coded it

```
var province = document.getElementById('#sfstate').value;
```

If you want to keep this as pure javascript, the hashtag should be removed.

```
var province = document.getElementById('sfstate').value;
```

Or do it the jQuery way

```
var province = $('#sfstate').val();
```

Comment: sir it doesn't work for some reason. do you think it's because how the form is being submitted? or retURL on the form?

Comment: I am panicking. I don't know what to do

Comment: Demo-Request-IC.html:173 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token }
all-page-pack.min.js:4 JQMIGRATE: Migrate is installed with logging active, version 1.4.1
all-page-pack.min.js:4 JQMIGRATE: jQuery.fn.load() is deprecated
e @ all-page-pack.min.js:4
all-page-pack.min.js:4 console.trace
e @ all-page-pack.min.js:4

Comment: I don't know what these mean actually.

Comment: Is all-page-pack.min.js a javascript library you included?  Perhaps it's an error coming from a Chrome or Firefox extension (I don't know what browser you're using).  Anyhow, if it's an extension you might want to either disable or uninstall it.